# Image relative and absolute path and .htaccess

Tags: image, .htaccess, codeigniter, relative-path, absolute-path

Hy all,

I'm playing around in Codeigneter and trying to make some kind of photo album just for fun ( to understand codeigneter better before i start for real ).

Now did i set up a test website here:
http://foal.scriptsenprogs.nl/

Now the thing is that users can upload an image in the future. And i want that image to be some kind of save...

So if somebody use this link:
http://foal.scriptsenprogs.nl/media/img/albums/1.png

It should be blocked (like it is now).

I've got this line of code in an .htacces file that is placed in `/media/img/albums` folder

```
<Directory "http://foal.scriptsenprogs.nl/media/img/albums" >
    Options Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

I must confess that i have little know-how about .htaccess files, but this seems to work ( the direct url is blocked ).

In my codeIgneter code i use this to add an image to an webpage:

```
$str .= '<div style="margin-top:20px;"><img width="200px" src="./media/img/albums/' . $imageStuff[$row['album_id']] -> img_id . '.' . $imageStuff[$row['album_id']] -> img_type . '" /></div>';
```

And before the .htaccess file, it worked. But now it isn't working.

If i check chromes error console i see this error:

```
GET http://foal.scriptsenprogs.nl/media/img/albums/1.png 404 (Not Found) foal.scriptsenprogs.nl:48
```

So an `404 Not Found` error it is then. But if you check the URL you see that it is conferted to an Absolute URL? But i inserted an Relative URL right?

Any thoughts of you guys on how to fix this?

**EDIT 1**
In de webroot of the subdomain, i've got the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|school|media|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT 2**
To clarify the question something more...

If your on the website ( http://foal.scriptsenprogs.nl/ ) the image must be showable done by using an relative path. ( like this: `<img width="200px" src="./media/img/albums/1.png" />` )

But if your trying to acces the image through an absolute path, it must be blocked ( the link will be something like this then: http://foal.scriptsenprogs.nl/media/img/albums/1.png )

Comment: I guess the obvious question is: Does `1.png` exist in folder `.../albums/`?

Comment: @faa, abvious, but yes, it exist. It even worked before i played with an .htaccess file ;P

Comment: The only thing you should need in your `/media/img/albums/.htaccess` is one line - `deny from all`

Comment: @Jeemusu, tried that, and it kind of works ( it deny's all). But i can't show the image on the webpage to... And i need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes CI and relative urls don't play nice together, try using the base_url function

```
'src="'.base_url().'media/img/albums/'
```

Comment: Done but doesn't work. It returns `http://foal.scriptsenprogs.nl/` what is right. But i want to block urls like that with `/media/img/albums/1.png`. But i want show them on the webpage. So i hoped i could do something like `./media/img/albums/1.png`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new rule to your existing `webroot/.htaccess` file.

Place the following after the `RewriteEngine On` line towards the top of your file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?yoursite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|jpg)$ /404.html [L]
```

This restricts access to any jpg,gif, etc to the domain http://yoursite.com, other requests are redirected to a 404 page.

NOTE: If you are testing this on a local server, you will be on the same domain as your site so it will most likely seem like nothing is happening.

Comment: Hy, thanks for your reply. I've edited my question and added the content of the webroot .htaccess. as you said i inserted your threee lines after the first line and changed `yoursite` to `scriptsenprogs`. And i deleted the contents of the .htaccess in `/media/img/albums/`. But i can see both of the pictures ( direct link in new tab and inclusion in webpage...

Comment: Is your site on a local server? I.E is the server on your local network, or on your computer?

Comment: It is on an real server. the adress is http://foal.scriptsenprogs.nl/ I try to do as least as possibly local because of the strange things sometimes :D

Comment: Didn't did it like that because it thought that this: `(.+\.)` was for the subdomain. Now the line is like this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?foal\.scriptsenprogs\.nl/ [NC]` but i can still view both the images...

Comment: if you write an incorrect domain, does the image become unviewable?

Comment: Only the image on the website, the image in new tab ( http://foal.scriptsenprogs.nl/media/img/albums/1.png ) isn't blocked then... That's strange right? or is it good??? Thank you for your patience btw ;)

Comment: And i wan't it the other way around then, so that the new tab image is blocked, but not on the website...